# tmux client-detached hook does not execute when terminal emulator closes

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, tmux

I have the following in my `.tmux.conf` file (and nothing else).

```
set-hook -g 'client-detached' 'run "echo DETACH >> .tmux.log"'
set-hook -g 'client-attached' 'run "echo ATTACH >> .tmux.log"'
```

I have ssh'd into the machine and attached to the session. The `client-attached` hook executes. If I detach the session using the command `detach-client` or `PREFIX b` from inside the session, the `client-detached` hook runs.

If instead, I close my terminal-emulator, the `client-detached` hook does not execute. I have tried this with iTerm2 on OSX, PuTTY on Windows and get the same behavior. How can I get the `client-detached` hook to run when the terminal emulator closes?

Comment: A bug related to this was fixed in 2.7. What version do you have?

Comment: I'm running debian unstable, package version is reported tmux/unstable,now 3.1c-1 amd64 [installed]